# Minecraft X-box compatibility

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am trying to find out if it is possible for users of different Xbox's (an Xbox-360 & an Xbox One) to play Minecraft together, in the same world over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft is not (yet) available for the Xbox One. It is unlikely that the versions will be compatible with each other when it does release.

Users of PC and Xbox 360 versions of Minecraft can not play together.

Comment: Ta TZHX - please forgive me for being stooped :) So when Minecraft is available for X-Box One, users of 360's won't be able to play on the same worlds as friends who have X-Box One's?

Comment: As one of the features for XBO's Minecraft is 'bigger worlds' and no other games currently feature 360<->XBO compatibility, the best answer to give is "Most likely not".

Comment: @RichardEngers you will have to ask that when the xbone version is released. No one can say for sure before it is.